# Define an indexed array of matrices in AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

I have to define an indexed set of matrices in AMPL (every set is a variable).

In particular, from 1 to N i want a variable M[i] that is a 4x4 matrix with elements >= 0.

How can i do it ?
Thanks so much

Comment: Usually we do this by creating a 3 dimensional variable `M[i,j,k]` where `j` and `k` are over `1..4`.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Erwin in a comment, you do this with a single three-dimensional variable.

```
param n;
var M{1..n,1..4,1..4} >= 0;
```